# Collectionview is broken when I change grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, collectionview

I have a list where can be one or more than grid. I am trying to use collectionview for this. But when I change grid, view of some collectionview items are broken (on iOS app). As in gif:
[image]

But when I swipe scroll, broken grids are getting better. My project is custom project. That's why I can't share sample app. But collectionview implementation is as follows:

```
<RefreshView Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
              IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
     <CollectionView x:Name="FlowListFileFolder" 
                 AutomationId="FileSystemPage_MainScreenListView"
                 IsGrouped="true"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding FlowListCloudItem}"
                 ItemsLayout="{Binding CollectionViewItemsLayout}">
         <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <StackLayout Style="{DynamicResource FlowListGroupTitleWrapperStyle}">
                     <Label Text="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource FlowListGroupTitleStyle}" />
                 </StackLayout>
             </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <local:ItemGridView LongPressEvent="Handle_LongPressEvent" SingleTapEvent="Handle_TappedEvent">
                     <local:CustomFolderFrame Style="{DynamicResource FspCiFrameWrapperStyle}" BorderColor="{Binding FrameColor}">
                         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding FrameColor}" Margin="1">
                             <Grid Style="{Binding FspCi_GridStyle}">
                                 <StackLayout AutomationId="FileSystemPage_FolderStackLayout" 
                                                      Style="{DynamicResource FspCiGeneralWrapperLayoutStyle}">
                                     <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle}">
                                         <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle}">
                                             <ff:CachedImage AutomationId="{Binding LvItemThumbnailSource, StringFormat='FolderIcon_{0}'}"
                                                                     Style="{Binding FspCiFolderThumbnailImageStyle}" />
                                             <ff:CachedImage Style="{Binding FspCiFileThumbnailImageStyle}" />
                                         </StackLayout>
    
                                         <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle}">
                                             <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="5">
    
                                                 <Label AutomationId="FileSystemPage_lblDisplayNameFolder" 
                                                                Text="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                                                                Style="{DynamicResource FspCiDisplayNameStyle}" />
                                                 <ff:CachedImage Source="group.png" Style="{Binding FspCiGroupIcon_ImageStyle}" />
                                             </StackLayout>
                                             <Label Text="{Binding CreationDate}" 
                                                            Style="{DynamicResource FspCiCreationDateStyle}" />
                                         </StackLayout>
                                     </StackLayout>
                                 </StackLayout>
    
                                 <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle}">
                                     <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiCheck_StackLayoutStyle}">
                                         <ff:CachedImage AutomationId="{Binding DisplayName, StringFormat='FileSystemPage_{0}_checked'}" 
                                                                 Source="checked.png" 
                                                                 Style="{Binding FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle}" />
                                     </StackLayout>
                                     <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiUncheck_StackLayoutStyle}">
                                         <ff:CachedImage AutomationId="{Binding DisplayName, StringFormat='FileSystemPage_{0}_unchecked'}" 
                                                                 Source="unchecked.png" 
                                                                 Style="{Binding FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle}" />
                                     </StackLayout>
                                     <StackLayout Style="{Binding FspCiMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle}">
                                         <ff:CachedImage AutomationId="FileSystemPage_ItemMoreDetail" 
                                                                 Source="ic_dots_gray.png" 
                                                                 Style="{Binding FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle}"/>
                                         <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                             <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ItemMoreDetail_Clicked" />
                                         </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                     </StackLayout>
                                 </StackLayout>
                             </Grid>
                         </StackLayout>
                     </local:CustomFolderFrame>
                 </local:ItemGridView>
             </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <CollectionView.Footer>
             <StackLayout Style="{DynamicResource FspCiFooterWrapperLayoutStyle}">
                 <Label Text="{Binding LabelFolderCount}" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource FspCiFooterFileFolderCountStyle}" />
                 <Label Text="{Binding LabelFileCount}" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource FspCiFooterFileFolderCountStyle}" />
             </StackLayout>
         </CollectionView.Footer>
     </CollectionView>
 </RefreshView>
```

For supporting different screens with one project, I had used different styles that changes according to device's viewport information. When app open, I gets device's viewport information and I set style that is suitable viewport. These styles gets from there.

And when I click grid button, I change some of these styles as follow:

```
public class FileSystemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
    
     protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
     {
         if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
             return;
         backingField = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
     }
    
     private ItemsLayout collectionViewItemsLayout;
     public ItemsLayout CollectionViewItemsLayout { get => collectionViewItemsLayout; set { SetValue(ref collectionViewItemsLayout, value); } }
    
     public Command GridClicked()
     {
         var btnGrid_Clicked = new Command(
             async () =>  {
                 if (FlowListGridCount == 1)
                 {
                     UpdateMultipleGrid();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     UpdateOneGrid();
                 }
             });
         return btnGrid_Clicked;
     }
    
    
     public void UpdateMultipleGrid()
     {
         foreach (var item in CloudItemList[0])
         {
             SetFolderTwoGridView(item);
         }
         foreach (var item in CloudItemList[1])
         {
             SetFileTwoGridView(item);
         }
         Helpers.Settings.FlowColumnCount = FlowListGridCount = ElementResolutionsHelper.GetPageFolderColumnCount(); //GetPageFolderColumnCount returns column count that is suitable with screen
         CollectionViewItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(FlowListGridCount, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);
     }
    
     public void UpdateOneGrid()
     {
         foreach (var item in CloudItemList[0])
         {
             SetFolderOneGridView(item);
         }
         foreach (var item in CloudItemList[1])
         {
             SetFileOneGridView(item);
         }
    
         Helpers.Settings.FlowColumnCount = FlowListGridCount = ElementResolutionsHelper.GetPageFolderColumnCount(); //GetPageFolderColumnCount returns 1 for this situation
         CollectionViewItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(FlowListGridCount, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);
     }
    
     private void SetFolderTwoGridView(CloudItemViewingResponse item)
     {
         if (item.IsShared)
             item.LvItemThumbnailSource = "folder_share.png";
         else
             item.LvItemThumbnailSource = "ic_folder.png";
    
         item.FspCiCheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiUncheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridUncheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_ImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFolderThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFolderThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFolderThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFileThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFileThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCi_GridStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFolder_GridStyle"]);
            
     }
    
     private void SetFileTwoGridView(CloudItemViewingResponse item)
     {
         item.FspCiCheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiUncheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridUncheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_ImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFileThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFolderThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFolderThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFileThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFileThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCi_GridStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiMultipleGridFile_GridStyle"]);
            
     }
    
     private void SetFolderOneGridView(CloudItemViewingResponse item)
     {
         if (item.IsShared)
             item.LvItemThumbnailSource = "folder_share.png";
         else
             item.LvItemThumbnailSource = "ic_folder.png";
    
         item.FspCiCheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiUncheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridUncheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_ImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFolderThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridFolderThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFileThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridFileThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCi_GridStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGrid_GridStyle"]);
     }
    
     private void SetFileOneGridView(CloudItemViewingResponse item)
     {
         item.FspCiCheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiUncheck_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridUncheck_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridMoreDetail_StackLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheck_ImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_ImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCheckUncheckMoreDetail_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridCloudItemInformation_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridThumbnailImage_WrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFolderThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridFolderThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiFileThumbnailImageStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridFileThumbnailImageStyle"]);
         item.FspCiThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGridThumbnailImageAndInformation_GeneralWrapperLayoutStyle"]);
         item.FspCi_GridStyle = (Style)((Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries).ElementAt((int)EStyleItem.DevicesStyle)["FspCiOneGrid_GridStyle"]);
     }
 }
```

We would change the HasUnevenRows or CachingStrategy value for the listview in case of such broken. Does collectionview have something like this?

And collectionview grid doesn't broken on Android. But when I change grid, it turns back at the top of the list. If I swipe to bottom, I don't want to turn back to top when I change grid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, whether the broken grids occurs randomly or always the same one will broke?

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, broken grid occurs randomly

Comment: Okey, it's strange. If the size of grid items is not too large, whether it will also occur?

Comment: When I change count of grids as multiple (it is not too large), it occurs again. Actually I can do same thing with flowlist. But I read some articles about collection view is more performant from listview. Flowlist inherited listview. That's why I tried to use collectionview, maybe my app can run more performant. But in my opinion collectionview has some issue for now. So that I give up to use collectionview for now.

Comment: Okey, it seems to be an issue for **CollectionView**, you could submit it as an issue in Github [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose).

Comment: I submitted it. Thank you for the help @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Great! You could share the Github link here when you have time, then I will also follow it up there.

Comment: Of course. [Link is here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13512)